# LNK2001 even though it is defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lnk2001

In a current project I am constructing a `Physics` namespace. in the file Core.h

```
extern real sleepEpsilon;/* = ((real).3);*/ // typedef float real; used, and works throughout project.
```

then in Core.cpp

```
real Physics::sleepEpsilon = ((real)0.3);
```

though I am receiving the error, and it is referring to another class that `#includes` Core.h, and I even went as far as to preface `Physics::` on all of them, but the LNK error still persists.

EDIT: included error

```
1>Body.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "float Physics::sleepEpsilon" (?sleepEpsilon@Physics@@3MA)
1>C:\...\Physics\Debug\Physics.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: would be good with some more info, maybe a copy of the error

Comment: have you tried: namespace Physics { extern real sleepEpsilon; }

Comment: @luskan it is defined in the namespace, and is considered global to the namespace, but in short yes that is how it is written

Comment: Seems like perhaps the object file produced from Core.cpp is not being included in your executable's final link?

Comment: @phonetagger is there any specif way that I can check that in VS2010

Comment: @FredericHamidi what exactly are you referring to? this is the only `extern` in the program currently.

Comment: @guardian06, yup, scratch that, the linker is obviously looking for C++ mangling (`?sleepEpsilon@Physics@@3MA`). Apologies for the noise.

Comment: three hypothesis: make sure that real name is not taken by some macro, maybe for experiment change its type to float. Also make sure your include is not by mistake in some other namespace. Maybe change to : namespace { real sleepEpsilon = ((real)0.3); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the folder which has Core.h is in your Additional Library directories under Linker->General in your project's property pages. This usually leads to LNK2001 errors.

Comment: I am actually building the namespace/library, and the linker is between files that both implement/extend the namespace

Comment: Are you building a DLL? What is the format of the output file that you are trying to generate?

Comment: I trying to create a namespace for clear inclusion, and resolution so it might just have a file that references the upper-level headers, so the clear answer is to treat the namespace as files that are part of the program.